# Gordon Freeman runs way too slowly!

Tags: half-life-series

In Half-Life 2: Episode One, my character, Dr. Gordon Freeman, runs really slowly. I can sprint but even then, he is still very slow. I'm also sure I'm not using 'WALK' by accident.

All the enemies and NPCs move at normal speed. The game runs perfectly on my machine. I have good graphics and sound quality, good FPS, and everything runs smoothly.

I've tried some in-game commands in the console like `cl_upspeed "320"` and `cl_forwardspeed "450"`, but nothing happens. It's like I'm playing the game in slow-motion mode.

My PC may be somewhat old but I am sure it can handle the game without a problem. This is my hardware:

- GRAPHICS CARD: AMD Radeon HD 7750
- CPU: Intel Core 2 6320 1.86 GHz
- RAM: 4 GB

How can I make Gordon Freeman run at normal speed?

Comment: how slow is slow? have you compared your speed to any online videos?

Comment: Are you using a gamepad? If so, are you sure the joystick still works?

Comment: @Colin D Yes, I streamed some online videos and did a compare, it's obviously that my character are in 'slow-motion' :(

Comment: @Nolonar No, just regular mouse and keyboard. I play Counter-Strike: Global Offensive too, it's all good.

Comment: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Source-1-Games/issues/1084

Comment: Are you using a mac, windows, or linux pc?

Comment: @ShotgunNinja Good catch. Seems to be a Linux specific issue then, although it might affect Mac OS X too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of methods that might fix this.

1. First, try typing "sv_alternateticks 0" into the console [(as linked by Shotgun Ninja above)](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Source-1-Games/issues/1084).
2. Try Alt-tabbing out of the game and back in. I've found this to be an issue with some Steam games, especially after opening the shift-tab dialog.
3. Change the shift-tab dialog's activation keys. This can be done [by clicking Steam>Settings>In Game>Click on "Press Shortcut Keys"](http://www.techvour.com/diy-how-to/how-to-change-shortcut-keys-to-open-steam-overlay-while-in-game/) and switching it to something else.
4. And if nothing else works, check your HL2 key bindings. You can find them under Esc Menu>Options>Keyboard. The ones you want to look out for are those set for walk/run.

Comment: Thanks all ! That magic command sv_alternateticks "0" saves Dr. Gordon Freeman.